# how to match non matching words in elasticsearch like "i phone" for documents like "iphone"

Tags: elasticsearch, inverted-index

i created two indexes fashion and mobiles with field "name".

```
client.indices.create(index='fashion',body={"mappings": {"doc": {"properties": {"name": {"type": "string"} } } } })
client.indices.create(index='mobiles',body={"mappings": {"doc": {"properties": {"name": {"type": "string"} } } } })
```

For Fashion, Following documents were added.

```
client.index(index='mobiles',doc_type='blog',body={"query":{ "name": "i shirts" }})
client.index(index='mobiles',doc_type='blog',body={"query":{ "name": "i celekon" }})
client.index(index='mobiles',doc_type='blog',body={"query":{ "name": "satsung" }})
```

For Mobiles:

```
client.index(index='mobiles',doc_type='blog',body={"query":{ "name": "apple iphone 6s" }})
client.index(index='mobiles',doc_type='blog',body={"query":{ "name": "samsung galaxy s2" }})
client.index(index='mobiles',doc_type='blog',body={"query":{ "name": "apple iphone 5s" }})
```

when i used match query to search for the term like

```
search="i phone"
test=client.search(index='mobiles,fashion',doc_type='blog',size=10,body={"query": {"bool" : {"should" : [{"match": {"name": {"query":search,"slop": 10,"max_expansions": 2 }}},{"match_phrase_prefix": {"name": {"query":search,"slop": 10,"max_expansions": 2}}},{"match": {"name": {"query":search, "fuzziness":1}}}]}}})
```

I get results in the following order..

> i shirts ,  i celekon , apple iphone 6s , apple iphone 5s

How could I following results?

> apple iphone 6s , apple iphone 5s, ....

How does "amazon", "flipkart" implement these types of searches?

**Note**: I used elasticsearch-py api to make the search.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a custom analyzer which would use [Word Delimiter Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html):

> Named `word_delimiter`, it splits words into subwords and performs
>   optional transformations on subword groups. Words are split into
>   subwords with the following rules:
>
> 1. split on intra-word delimiters (by default, all non alpha-numeric
>      characters). "Wi-Fi" → "Wi", "Fi"
> 2. split on case transitions: "PowerShot" → "Power", "Shot"
> 3. split on letter-number transitions: "SD500" → "SD", "500"
> 4. leading and trailing intra-word delimiters on each subword are
>      ignored: "//hello---there, dude" → "hello", "there", "dude"
> 5. trailing "'s" are removed for each subword: "O’Neil’s" → "O", "Neil"

I think you're looking for second example. If you'd be indexing `iPhone`, it would create tokens `"i"` and `"Phone"`, which is what you're looking for.

One thing to keep in mind, that you should look after `"preserve_original"` parameter there and set it to true, so it does keep original word. It matters because user can be looking for both i Phone and iPhone and it would still score.

Comment: if "iphone" is lower case how would we do it @Evaldas Buinauskas

Comment: You apply `lowercase` token filter right after this, then iPhone iphone iphone and i phone should be recognized as same keywords.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options here

1. [Synonym analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) - You can map the variants or synonym as a single set here.
2. [Compound token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html) - This plugin is capable of breaking a word into possible tokens.